# Blender Video Editing Output differs from Preview

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I try to make a short movie clip using Blender's video sequence editor. I'm using 6 different clips which I want to put together using transitions. The clips are distributed around 4 different channels/tracks.

I'm using Blender 2.72b on Linux with all ffmpeg codecs and everything installed.

**My problem is:**

All looks excactly as I want it to in the preview on the upper right, but the rendered video is completely different.

Some (not all) Gamma Cross transitions are simply black and the some of the single clips are too long although I've cut and deleted the unwanted parts.

All these wrong/broken transitions and cuts work if I only render the transition plus minus 10 frames or something. So only the whole video together is broken, but consisting of working parts.

**This is what it looks like in the Blender preview**

[image]

**This is what I get as output**

[image]

So the gamma cross transition is replaced by a much shorter gamma cross from black.

Don't wonder about different image sizes, this is only my incapability of making proper screenshots.

Can I force Blender to render the video exactly as in the preview window? Or does anyone have an idea what's going on?

**Screenshot of the whole Blender Window**

[image]

Comment: Please at least put image(s) here to show the comparison.

Comment: I added some screenshots. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Could you upload your .blend or take a screenshot of Blender while in the video editor?

Comment: I added the screenshot. If it's helpful i will upload the .blend file. But i think it doesn't make sene without the corresponding video files, does it?
Please also read my comment under the one answer, I think this really could be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell for certain, but I'll hazard a guess that it is a codec issue. Render the sequences to JPEGs or TIFFs, and see if it persists. Bi directional frames can wreak havoc on your Presentation Time Stamps (PTS). Hence why some codecs are poorly suited for editing.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a **gamma issue**. Make sure your Color Management is set up correctly. You can try to set your gamma value to `2.2` and make sure `sRGB` is the color space for the sequencer to display the preview in the right color space.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately this changed nothing. It is still the same. I have the feeling we are looking at the wrong place. A new hint could be, that all my clips last longer in the render than i made the (soft) cuts in the timeline/preview. So parts i cut out and deleted are in the render. Is it possible that it's something getting out of sync? like framerate or something? atm i render it in the same framerate as the media information tells me about my clips